# Multithreaded access to files in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file, server, filechannel

I'm working on a multithreaded server in Java.
The server monitors a directory of files. Clients can ask the server:

- to download a file from the server directory
- to upload a new version of an already existing file to the server, overwriting the old version in the server directory.

To do the transfers, I'm planning to use FileChannels and SocketChannels, using the methods transferFrom and transferTo. According to the documentation, these two methods are thread safe.
The thing is that a single call to these two function could not be sufficient to read/write the file entirely.

The problem arises if there are more than one request on the same file at the same time. In this scenario, multiple threads could be doing read/write operations on the same file. Now, the single calls to transferFrom/transferTo are thread safe, according to the Java documentation. But a single call to these two functions could not be sufficient to read/write the file entirely. If thread A is replying to a download request and thread B is replying to an upload request referring to the same file, it could happen that:

1. Thread A starts reading from the file
2. In thread A, for some reason the read call returns before the EOF
3. Thread B overwrites the entire file with a single write call
4. Thread A continues reading from the file

In this case, the downloading client receives a portion of the old version and a portion of the new version.

---

To solve this I think I should be using some sort of locking, but I'm not sure how to do it in an efficient way. I could create two synchronized methods for reading and writing, but that creates obviously too much contention.

The best solution I have in mind is to use lock striping. Before doing any read/write operation, an hash based on the filename is calculated. Then, the lock in position lockArr[hash % numOfLocks] is acquired.
I think also that I should be using ReadWriteLocks, since multiple simultaneous reads should be allowed.

Now, this is my analysis of the problem and I could be completely wrong. Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: You maybe could clarify what consistency your system has. E.g. "a read made at T, sees the full file as it was a T. If a write comes at T0 and finishes at T1, then the uploaded file is seeable on any request that arrives after T1. If two writes happen concurrently, between W1start ->W1end, and between W2start->W2end, then the upload that finishes first becomes visible at Min(W1end, W2end) and the last after Max(W2end, W1end)." Do you have any such specification ? It could be much simpler "only whole uploaded files are read, no matter which version if multiple reads/writes are concurrent".

Comment: @GPI: Yeah sure. I forgot to say that only one thread at a time can overwrite a file (due to implementation details), so there is no problem with concurrent writes. However one write and multiple reads can happen simultaneously. A read made at time T must read the full file as it is at T. I don't have a particular specification about what should happen if reads and writes overlap. However, I'd prefer to always read the new version of the file only when the upload is completely finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locking means that somebody has to wait for somebody else -- not the best solution.

When the client uploads a file, you should write it out to a temp file on the same disk (usually in the same directory), and then when the file upload is done:

1. Rename the old version to a temporary name.  Any current readers should be forced to close the old one, re-open the temp version, and seek to the correct position.
2. Rename the uploaded file to the target file name.
3. Delete the temp version of the old file when any readers are done with it.

In a typical implementation, you'd need a centralized class (lets call it `ConcurrentFileAccessor`) to manage the interactions between threads.

Readers would need to register with this class, and synchronize on some object during the actual read operation.  When an upload completes, the writer would have to claim all those locks to block reads, close all the read files, rename the old version, reopen, seek, and then release them to allow the readers to continue.

Comment: I had in mind this solution, but I don't know how to implement it. In 1), how can I signal the other threads that they should close the old file and open the new one? Moreover, is it legal to rename a file while it is being read? Also, in 3) I really don't know how I should check if the old file is still being read.

Comment: Yeah, concurrency is hard.  I made an edit that hopefully will help, but I can tell you're new to this sort of work, so it's gonna be tough.

Comment: "Readers would need to register with this class, and synchronize on some object during the actual read operation" So the class would manage every single reader and writer active in the server, right? In this case, an upload that will overwrite file A would block every other reader, including those that aren't reading from file A. Isn't that too much contention? "...the writer would have to claim all those locks to block reads" Do you mean I have to interrupt all the threads that acquired the locks?

Comment: You would have to be careful about synchronization in this class, in fact the purpose of this class is to manage the complex concurrency requirements, so no, using such a class doesn't mean the a writer would block every single reader.  There would be a separate monitor object for each reader, and a writer would lock those objects to block just the readers of the same file.  No, it wouldn't interrupt the readers -- the reading threads would have to acquire its lock while reading, probably through an `InputStream` subclass

Comment: I tried to interpret what you suggested and this is what I've got right now. A few things are unclear to me, but I just want to know if I'm on the right path.

Comment: A concurrent map maps a filename to a list of ReaderMonitors. When a reader thread starts reading from a file, it adds a new ReaderMonitor to the list associated with the filename key. Then it starts calling ReaderMonitor's read method multiple times until EOF. This method is protected by the object's lock. When a writer finishes writing to the temp file, it acquires the locks of every ReaderMonitor object in the list found in the map. Then it closes the old file, renames it, renames the new file to target, changes the file references in the monitors, seeks and then it releases the locks.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.  You also need to lock the list of monitors when accessing/modifying it and in the writer completion step